# Changing position of absolute element without container overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, absolute

Maybe an obvious question but how do I make an element with a absolute position not overflow its container when moving it's position right? I know I could change it to relative position or move it 99% but for my project that won't due. I tried using margins, padding, object-fit, all with no success. Thanks for any help

```js
var green = document.getElementById('green');

function myFunct() {
    green.style.right = '100%';
}
```

```css
    h1 {
        position: relative;
        width: 80%;
        height: 100px;
        margin: auto;
        background-color: red; 
    }
    
    #green {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: green;
        width: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<h1>
<div id = 'green'></div>
    </h1>
    
<button onclick="myFunct()">FindHighScore</button>
```

Comment: <div> tag can not put in  <h1> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS `calc()`

```
var green = document.getElementById("green");

function myFunct() {
  green.style.right = "calc(100% - 20px)";
}
```

Or, apply `left: 0` and `right: auto` (reset)

```
var green = document.getElementById("green");

function myFunct() {
  green.style.left = "0";
  green.style.right = "auto";
}
```

A `<div>` should not be in a `<h1>` tag by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `overflow` to `hidden` at parent container.

`<h1>` permitted content is [Phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content)

```js
var green = document.getElementById('green');

function myFunct() {
  green.style.right = '100%';
}
```

```css
div:not(#green) {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#green {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id='green'></div>
</div>

<button onclick="myFunct()">FindHighScore</button>
```